# filter a list of nested dictionary using loops

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, tree

I've got a List of dict like below.

The structure of it is similar to a tree in which each node has an arbitray number of children. i want to select the node that has a matching 'name' that is provided as input.

```
newdata = [
    {'name':"Oli Bob", 'location':"United Kingdom", '_children':[
        {'name':"Mary May", 'location':"Germany"},
        {'name':"Christine Lobowski", 'location':"France"},
        {'name':"Brendon Philips", 'location':"USA",'_children':[
            {'name':"Margret Marmajuke", 'location':"Canada"},
            {'name':"Frank Harbours", 'location':"Russia",'_children':[{'name':"Todd Philips", 'location':"United Kingdom"}]},
        ]},
    ]},
    {'name':"Jamie Newhart", 'location':"India"},
    {'name':"Gemma Jane", 'location':"China", '_children':[
        {'name':"Emily Sykes", 'location':"South Korea"},
    ]},
    {'name':"James Newman", 'location':"Japan"},
]
```

Currently i am doing this, using below

```
op = []

def getInfo(list_of_dict, name):
    for dict1 in list_of_dict:
        if dict1["name"]==name:
            op.append(dict1)
        if "_children" in dict1:
            getInfo(dict1["_children"], name)

getInfo(newdata, "Gemma Jane")  
print(op)
```

i would want to perform the same without an external variable(list).

when i try to do the same using below function

```
def getInfo(list_of_dict, name):
    for dict1 in list_of_dict:
        if dict1["name"]==name:
            return dict1
        if "_children" in dict1:
            return getInfo(dict1["_children"], name)

op = getInfo(newdata, "James Newman")
```

It enters a recursive loop and doesnt provide correct output for all values.

Any suggestion to fix this issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursive generator function to search for the nodes. For example:

```py
def getInfo(data, name):
    if isinstance(data, list):
        for value in data:
            yield from getInfo(value, name)
    elif isinstance(data, dict):
        if data.get("name") == name:
            yield data
        yield from getInfo(data.get("_children"), name)


for node in getInfo(newdata, "Gemma Jane"):
    print(node)
```

Prints:

```py
{'name': 'Gemma Jane', 'location': 'China', '_children': [{'name': 'Emily Sykes', 'location': 'South Korea'}]}
```